# x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Using python I'm trying to plot a sin wave and random distribution, then show where the ratio is greater than or equal to 3.

I think I'm 90% of the way there but keep getting the error message 'x and y must be the same size' when I try to plot it. I've been racking my brains but can't figure out what I'm missing.

Any help or pointers gratefully received.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r= 2*math.pi
dev = 0.1
x = np.array(np.arange(0, r, dev))
y1 = np.array(np.sin(x))
y2 = np.array(np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=63))

mask = y1//y2 >= 3

fit = np.array(x[mask])

print(fit)


plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.scatter(x, fit)
plt.scatter(x, y2, marker=".")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but this will scatter dots on the sin-curve corresponding to your mask.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r= 2*math.pi
dev = 0.1
x = np.array(np.arange(0, r, dev))
y1 = np.array(np.sin(x))
y2 = np.array(np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.1, size=63))

mask = y1//y2 >= 3

fit_x = np.array(x[mask])
fit_y = np.array(y1[mask])


plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.scatter(fit_x, fit_y)
plt.scatter(x, y2, marker=".")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert this line into your code, just before the point of error:

```
print(len(x), len(fit))
```

Output:

```
63 28
```

You explicitly removed elements from your sequence, and then expected them to be of the same size.  You still have 63 `x` values, but now only 28 `y` values.  Since you didn't trace the problem and explain what you intend for this scatter plot, I have no way of knowing what a "fix" might be.  Perhaps make a list of point (x-y pairs), and then filter *that* for the appropriate y1/y2 ratio?

Answer (score 0):

In your line `plt.scatter(x, fit)` you are trying to scatter your x-values with your fit-values. However fit is only of size 25 file while x is of size 63 (as are y1 and y2 btw., thats why that part works).

`mask` is basically an array of False or True values. That means if you use the `np.array(x[mask])` function. It will only create an array of the values where x is actually True, which seems to be what you want. But you can only scatter this against something like `np.array(np.sin(fit))`, otherwise the sizes are incompatible to scatter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    """## Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set"""
    
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)

print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

"""## Training the Simple Linear Regression model on the Training set"""

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

"""## Predicting the Test set results"""

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

"""## Visualising the Training set results"""

plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color = 'green')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'yellow')
plt.title('Doctor visits(Training set)')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()

"""## Visualising the Test set results"""

plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Doctor visits (Test set)')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).